# How to subscribe() to a combineReducer on Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux-form

I`m using Redux on react-native with redux and react-redux. I use combinereducers() to combine two reducers:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  sessiontype,
  userdata
})
```

Now I subscribe to some change in my reducers:

```
   store.subscribe((state, previousState) => {

       //Do something

    });
```

How I subscribe only to my userdata reducer? Because when I change the state of my sessiontype reducer I need to change the state of my userdata reducer (and It create a infinite cycle in my store.subscribe() because detect the whole reducer has modified.... (sorry my bad english)

Answer (score 2):

The concept around Redux is that you have only one `state` and one `reducer`. The idea that you have separate reducers is just an implementation detail introduced by `combineReducers()` - it allows you to think of your reducers in parts, but to your application there's simply one `reducer`. Check out the discussion on [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2060http://).

The `mapStateToProps` function inside the `react-redux` package allows you to select what parts of a `reducer` a component has access to. This may help you solve your issue. When a component with access to `sessiontype` updates the `reducer`, you can have that same component update `userdata`. To do that, you simply `dispatch` two separate actions to the `store`. Also, remember that `subscribe` does not actually give you access to the `store` - it simply let's you know that something has changed. Inside your `subscribe` function, you need to call `getState()` to actually read the data. Read more [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-subscriptions).

Try something like this:

```
store.subscribe((state, prevState) => {

  // run a check of conditions for an action being dispatched
  // if you don't specify conditions, you'll end up in an
  // infinite loop
  if (stateHasFieldOrValue) {

     // dispatch update to sessiontype
     store.dispatch(updateSessionType(payload));

     // dispatch update to userdata
     store.dispatch(updateUserData(payload));
  }
});
```